# Dapper Semi-Dynamic Typing?

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I have a table with a similar schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Property](
[id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[PropertyOccupantTypeId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[PropertyStatusId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
-- Other potential columns
)
```

It has a lot of lookup values on it that my user doesn't need to know anything about. They just need the `PropertyStatus` not the `PropertyStatusId`

Assuming the lookup tables have 2 columns each (guid: id, varchar: value) Is there a way to write a query similar to:

```
SELECT p.id,
       po.value as OccupantType,
       ps.value as PropertyStatus
       -- Other potential columns
FROM Property p 
     join PropertyOccupantType po on p.PropertyOccupant = po.id 
     join PropertyStatus ps on p.PropertyStatusId = ps.id
```

and have that map to a `Property` object which looks like:

```
public class Property
{
    public Guid id;
    public string PropertyOccupant;
    public string PropertyStatus;
}
```

Or do I need to query the additional tables manually and map the values that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine.  Dapper doesn't care what query you write. It simply matches column names from the result set with the property names of your object.